# Is there a way to remove everything in my Android phone Contacts and then transfer everything in Gmail contacts into the phone contacts?

Tags: sync, google-contacts

I make extensive use of GROUPS in my Gmail account.  For example, all medical contacts are stored in MEDICAL, restaurants in RESTAURANTS, etc.  When doing this I specifically do not have the group entry appear in MY CONTACTS.  This removes clutter from MY CONTACTS.  I have 97 entries in MY CONTACTS, and 300 entries among the groups that do not appear in MY CONTACTS.  Somewhere I COPIED my Gmail to my phone contacts and to my surprise all the group entries from Gmail now also appear in MY CONTACTS on the phone which results in 397 phone contacts (97 + 300).  I would like the phone contacts to be exactly as they appear in the Gmail contacts.

I have tried Settings > More > Applications > Go right to all apps > scroll down to "Contacts Storage" Then clicked on contacts storage > Click Clear Data but that did not do the job.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want a particular contact group to appear in the contacts app on your phone, then you can achieve it pretty easily by using the Contacts to display option in your Contacts app.

1. Open Contacts app.
2. Tap on the 3 dots at top right, choose Settings.
3. Select *Contacts to display* > customize.
4. Expand your Google account and uncheck all the other groups and keep only *My Contacts*.

[image]

Do note that when performing a search within contacts, it will still search within all the available contacts. But under normal display it will only show your 97 contacts stored under *My Contacts* group.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That solved my problem.  Under my Gmail account I checked MY CONTACTS and STARRED IN ANDROID and nothing else.  That is all that displayed under CONTACTS which is what I wanted.  I was still able to see individual entries in my various groups, which is also what I wanted.  Thanks again for helping me out.

Comment: @Donald Baltz I am glad that it has helped. Please consider up-voting the answer as that will help me in gaining some reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

It depend on your device model. You should check the setting of contact application. You can disable google contact to show in contact application. By the way, Go to [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/). Export contact list to a csv file. Import this file on your device and check the groups.

Comment: I Exported MY CONTACTS (97 records) from Gmail in vCard format and imported them into my phone's contacts.  The 300 entries from the various Gmail Groups that are not part of Gmail MY CONTACTS remain in the phone's CONTACTS.  I would have liked for them to have been removed (OR NOT APPEAR) in the phone's CONTACTS.